# How to write function to help distinguish empty values versus 0?

Tags: c++

I am trying to calculate the average based on input from a vector. How can I distinguish to the caller of my function that an empty vector was provided versus a vector with just 0 values? Can I do both in one function or do I need 2 functions?

Comment: Could you please post the code you have tried so far?

Comment: you may be looking for [templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates)

Comment: Return a std::optional average so the caller can tell if the average was calculated or not. 
Or have an output parameter that stores the number of items averaged?  Or returns a struct that has the average and some sort of flag (like the count)

Comment: It is dim what you need. If you calculate average of empty std::vector<double> then the result of sum of its elements 0.0 divided by count of its element 0 is NaN. With at least one zero in vector you get 0.0/1 that is 0.0. So there is already difference for caller without doing nothing special.

Answer (score 5):

You could return a `std::optional<T>` to signal that the your function may not return an actual value in the case of an empty vector.

```
std::optional<double> avg(const std::vector<int>& n) {
    if(n.size() < 1)
        return std::nullopt;
    return std::accumulate(n.begin(), n.end(),0) / static_cast<float>(n.size());
}


int main() {

    std::vector<int> numbers;
    auto average = avg(numbers);
    if(average) {
        std::cout << "the average is" << average.value() << std::endl;
    }else {
        std::cout << "Could not compute average!" << std::endl;

    }
}
```

Comment: You mix `double` and `float` :-/

Answer (score 1):

You can use templates to do what you want as [follows](https://onlinegdb.com/ZkzkMEN3h):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
template<typename T>
T average(const std::vector<T> &vec)
{
    if(vec.empty())
    {
        //you can also assert instead of throw
        throw std::runtime_error("Vector passed is empty");//throw if the vector is empty because we don't want to operate on an empty vector
    }
    T sum{};
    for(T elem: vec)
    {
        sum += elem;
    }
    return sum/vec.size();
}
int main()
{
   std::vector<float> myvec1{1,2,3.4};
   std::cout<<"average is: "<<average(myvec1);
   
   std::vector<int> myvec2;
   average(myvec2);//this will (terminate)print "vector passed is empty"

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I agree the templates allow you to average both floats and ints, but the templates part doesn't answer the actual question.  You are basically answering the question by saying "throw an exception if the vector is empty"

Comment: Throw an uncaught exception is likely bad advice to apparent novice.

Comment: @ÖöTiib This is not an intro to "how to write try catch blocks". I have just shown one way to do it. The OP is free to learn more about them from books/other resources.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Maybe i misunderstood the OP's question. Though i think that the OP should add more information to his/her question(like some example input and outputs and what he/she has tried till now). I tried to give an answer that i think was about what the OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

An empty vector has no average, it is undefined, just like 0/0 is undefined. It is the caller's responsibility not to calculate 0/0, and it is the caller's responsibility not to calculate an empty vector average.

There is no good way to deal *nicely* with undefined calculations such as 0/0 or empty vector average in C++. The usual approach is to let the users sort it out. The caller should check the length of the vector before trying to call your function. Otherwise the callee would need to check the length, return a special value, and then the caller would need to check that the returned value is special. This is unneeded complexity. If the user needs to check every call, let them check every call before making it, not after. Just add an `assert` to help debugging.

Alternative approaches would be to return a NaN or to throw an exception. This allows the users to validate calculation results with whatever granularity they want.